# Sharepoint 2013 Resources location

Tags: 2013, view, resources

I need to find what the resource key is for "All Documents" (=View on document library) in SharePoint 2013. Does anyone know where or how to find this?

If I get the the View.TitleResource (in c#), it's made from _ViewTitle[<Guid>], but it's not possible to use this myself to get the resource value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources location hasn't changed since [2007](/questions/tagged/2007) or [2010](/questions/tagged/2010).

Try looking in `%SYSTEMROOT%\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources` for local resources.

If you can't find the Resource file having it there, then try the Global Resources folder in `%SYSTEMROOT%\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<YourSiteFolderHere>`